# ! Missing \endcsname inserted in \begin {algorithmic}

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx, algorithmic

file1.tex:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Xiaodi add:

\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand{\argmin}{\arg\!\min}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{color,amsmath,latexsym,amssymb}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{algorithm} 
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
%\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[algorithm]{font=footnotesize}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{algcompatible}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\newcounter{assum}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
\include{file2}
\end{document}
```

file2.tex (version 1)

```
\section{Test}
\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
\state Hi
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

Error corresponding to version 1:
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
 
                   \protect 
l.3 \begin
          {algorithmic}
?

Comment: I'm unable to replicate your current problem with the code you posted, sorry. Please read the following link: [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) Your current code doesn't adhere to that...

Comment: @user69836: With your edit I receive a different error, relating to the fact that you're using an EMPTY `algorithmic` (list) environment. Since it has no `\item` (created by commands like `\State`), it throws an error. So, again, please provide a minimal example that replicates the error you state.

Comment: The issue is I need to have two separate files...did you have the codes in 2 separate files?

Comment: @user69836: Yes. And if you saw the linked post, it suggest using `filecontents` to create a MWE with separate files in it.

Comment: You cannot have got those errors from the code you posted because the code you posted does not use the `\caption` command at all, yet one of the errors is clearly about that command. Also, you should make sure that we have the same number of lines so that the line numbers in the error messages reference lines which exist for us!

Comment: In the early part of my code, I did mention that if I change my code to...\caption...I got this error...If my code does not have \caption, it has a different type of error.

Comment: @user69836 no need to apologise, just fix the question. Just make a document that has the error and doesn't load any packages not needed for the example, and then post the error message generated by _the document as posted_. for example the \caption error you show is generated on line 14, but the version you show with \caption has that command on line 3, so presumably a different document.

Comment: The thing is I have some other things above the algorithm...but I don't want to publicize all...It is possible that those things above may affect the compilation...A lesson learned is that I am going to create a new file of just algorithm to see where the error comes from...

Comment: @user69836: There is no `\state` macro.

Comment: @user69836: See [How do I mark code blocks?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192/5764)

Comment: @user69836: Delete your `.aux`, `.toc`, `.lof` and `.lot` file and retry. Perhaps it could be due to a faulty `.aux` that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Minimising your example (which hardly depended on TiKZ or external graphics and what have you), you just need to add something to the algorithm you are defining. I haven't checked, but I assume that it is defined as a `list` environment, and that it therefore expects an `\item`. The relevant commands defined by the packages you are loading will themselves be defined in terms of `\item`, so that you do not need to call it directly (which makes the error a bit misleading if you are not used to this kind of thing).

For example, this works:

```
\begin{filecontents}{a.tex}
  Newton's method except for the computation of derivatives.\\
  \begin{algorithm}
    \begin{algorithmic}
      \State 1
    \end{algorithmic}
  \end{algorithm}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
  \input{a}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Yes, this works...but the thing is I need to have it in 2 separate files...

Comment: @user69836 So? I just combined them for the MWE. If you say `\input{filename}`, it is just the same as including the code in the main file directly.

Comment: @user69836 I've updated my answer. It works fine for me.

Comment: I trusted you...just that I cannot figure out why mine did not compile...